# Operator overloading % into the modulus of complex number

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to operator overload for a complex number, I have implemented a class where it takes in real and imaginary part. I am trying to overload the `%` operator where it return a modulus value(length of the real and imaginary), but I am getting error "must take exactly one argument", What am I doing wrong?

Here is my header file

complex.h

```
class complex{
     private:
          double rm;
          double im;
     public:
          void operator % ();
```

complex.cpp

```
void operator %(){
      complex c;
      c.re = pow(re,2);
      c.im = pow(im,2);
      return c;
```

Thank you!

Comment: `%` is a binary operator.

Comment: This is the correct signature (using inside class definition): `complex operator%(const complex& other);`

Comment: double rm should be 're'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '%' operator in C++ is a binary operator, like `a % b`, but you are trying to use it like a unary one. C++ allows you to overload the implementation of existing operators, but not add new ones or change how existing ones are used.

Comment: thank you! I was also wondering how would I make it that it only outputs the return variable as an int instead of my defined class ?

Answer (score 0):

`operator%` is a binary operator (some, like `operator-` can be unary or binary).

This means that you can define it in two different ways.

1. As a standalone function

   `complex operator%(const complex& left, const complex& right);`
2. As a class member function, in which case the 'left' term is implicitly this

   `complex& complex::operator%(const complex& right);`

I see a few more issues with your code. Usually in C++ `%` means the modulus or remainder. With complex numbers the modulus is the [norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) implemented in `abs` and it returns a real. I guess this is to make things clearer, especially when there are expressions that mix complex and real numbers. In your modulus operator you are simply squaring the real and imaginary components. I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the `%` operator is a binary operator so repurposing it as a unary modulus is not possible.

Having said that, we can abuse the free function binary operator in order to provide syntactic sugar.

*Note* This answer is for fun and in the spirit of learning. It is not a recommendation of a coding style.

```
#include <cmath>

struct imperative_mode_sentinel {};

struct complex
{
    complex(double rm, double im) : rm(rm), im(im) {}
    double rm, im;

    complex modulus() const
    {
        return complex(std::pow(rm, 2), std::pow(im, 2));
    }
};

auto operator%(imperative_mode_sentinel, complex const& r) -> complex
{
    return r.modulus();
}


constexpr static auto imperative_mode = imperative_mode_sentinel();

int main()
{
    auto c = complex(1,1);

    auto d = imperative_mode %c; // equivalent to d = c.modulus()
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If this is your modulus operator, it is fine. you can give it whatever meaning you want. [See](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators);

> Other than the restrictions above, the language puts no other
>   constraints on what the overloaded operators do, or on the return type
>   (it does not participate in overload resolution), but in general,
>   overloaded operators are expected to behave as similar as possible to
>   the built-in operators

```
class complex{
    private:
      double rm;
      double im;
    public :
          complex(int i, int r) {
              re = r; im = i;
          }
          complex operator%(const complex& mc){//for complex

                return complex(pow(re,2),pow(im,2)) ;
          }
};
```

Comment: This will not even compile. You forgot the return type, you used incorrect class name in the `operator%` argument and you didn't even explain to OP what he did wrong.

Comment: Where is `MyClass` from, how does that help the OP's use case?

Comment: Corrected it, and variable names, too.